# http://phpmyadmin.app:8000 is working fine in Firefox but not for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, phpmyadmin, vagrant, homestead

Using vagrant i created phpmyadmin.app for phpmyadin
http://phpmyadmin.app:8000 is working fine in firfox but not for crome. Why is that . Any one have a clue to fix.

Error>>>
This webpage is not available

ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION
Hide details
This site is using a new generic top-level domain (gTLD). If you have used phpmyadmin.app to access an internal site in the past, contact your network administrator.
<<<<

Comment: Sound like Chrome does not like the `.app` TLD in your hostname. How is that hostname being resolved?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/919278/err-icann-name-collision-when-trying-to-use-localhost-dev-in-chrome

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara hosts 127.0.0.1  phpmyadmin.app

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts):
It should include:

```
192.168.70.10 epass.app
```

Where 192.168.70.10 - ip of vagrant.